# Combine items in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I made an MySQL database. the field are: `ID:NAME:QUANTITY`

I do have for example:

```
ID:NAME:QUANTITY
1: APPLE: 3
1: APPLE: 4
2: BANANA: 1
2: BANANA: 2
```

Instead of having this output, I would like to get:

```
APPLE 7
BANANA 3
```

I have tried so many things, but I failed again and again. Do you guys have a solution?

My code is:

```
 public function getList($user_id, $recept_id) {

  $return = array();
  $sql = "select * from list";

  $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $return[] = $row;
  }
  return($return);
```

Comment: Aggregate function `SUM` with `GROUP BY`

Comment: `select name, sum(quantity) as cnt from table group by name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply sum the quantity in your query.

```
SELECT `NAME`, SUM(`QUANTITY`) as QUANTITY FROM list GROUP BY `NAME`;
```

---

For your code:

```
  $return = array();
  $sql = "SELECT `NAME`, SUM(`QUANTITY`) as QUANTITY FROM list GROUP BY `NAME`";

  $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $return[] = $row;
  }
  return($return);
```

Comment: Sorry guys, but don't get I think.
WHERE should I add this code? In the PHP code, or somewhere in MySQL?

Comment: You need to replace your current query with above one. If you need further help, feel free to add the code that generates your current array to the question. @Robbert

Comment: Edited the answer @Robbert

Comment: I did exactly as above, but the output is blank.

Comment: Strange. The columns are named as in the query? @Robbert

Comment: Yes, I checked that multiple times :)

Comment: It works, there was a STR_REPLACE somewhere with the wrong names. THANKS!

Answer (score -2):

edited sum instead of count.

use the `SUM` function, something like this should work

```
SELECT NAME,SUM(QUANTITY) as QUANTITY FROM list GROUP BY NAME ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC;
```

Comment: Not `count(*)` nor `sum(*)`

Comment: `sum`. But just for field rather than for a wildcard.

Comment: using count with group by will make it work ;) give it a shot

Comment: @baao oh god, i got his question wrong. Yep count wont work :D 
updating the answer xD

Comment: Cool. Now it's a syntax error... hint `SUM(QUANTITY)` instead of `SUM(*)`

Comment: Now it does the same as with count. You need to sum the quantity, not the name